# Spark write.parquet runs on executors but read.parquet runs on driver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running Spark 3.2.0 on Kubernetes.  The driver is running in a pod.  The executors pods are configured to all attach to the same shared PV.  I'm generating data, saving it to the shared PV, and then trying to reload the data.  Saving the data seems to work as expected but loading does not:

(the Spark code here is based on this repo: https://github.com/bigstepinc/SparkBench/)

```
# cat /tmp/spark.properties
spark.driver.port=7078
spark.master=k8s\://https\://10.10.1.2\:6443
spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.options.claimName=spark-pvc
spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.mount.path=/var/data
spark.app.name=spark-testing
spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.data.mount.readOnly=false
spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
spark.driver.host=spark-driver-svc.default.svc
spark.driver.blockManager.port=7079
spark.app.id=spark-3834e87e5d1241dc8834c53d3f170281
spark.kubernetes.container.image=xxx
spark.kubernetes.memoryOverheadFactor=0.4
spark.kubernetes.submitInDriver=true
spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-driver
spark.executor.instances=3

# /opt/spark/bin/spark-shell --properties-file /tmp/spark.properties --deploy-mode client 
--conf spark.driver.bindAddress=<this pod's address>

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

scala> val spark=SparkSession.getDefaultSession.get
spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@2b720a2c

scala> val chars = 'A' to 'Z'
chars: scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Char] = NumericRange A to Z

scala> val randValue = udf( (rowId:Long) => { 
     | val rnd = new scala.util.Random(rowId)
     | (1 to 100).map( i => chars(rnd.nextInt(chars.length))).mkString
     | })
randValue: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = SparkUserDefinedFunction($Lambda$3296/0x000000084135f040@27cac84b,StringType,List(Some(class[value[0]: bigint])),Some(class[value[0]: string]),None,true,true)

scala> val df=spark.range(1000).toDF("rowId").repartition(3)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [rowId: bigint]

scala> val df2=df.withColumn("value", randValue(df("rowId")))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [rowId: bigint, value: string]

scala> df2.write.parquet("/var/data/testing2")
```

At this point the parquet files are on the PV.  From a pod with the PV attached at `/var/data`:

```
# find /var/data/testing2/ -name "*.parquet" -exec ls -lh {} \;
-rw-r--r-- 1 185 root 37K Jan 28 15:56 /var/data/testing2/_temporary/0/task_20220128155613744592892460434050_0003_m_000001/part-00001-6560f650-2a21-4e2a-a13c-c293ed63244f-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 185 root 37K Jan 28 15:56 /var/data/testing2/_temporary/0/task_202201281556136846007947886921010_0003_m_000000/part-00000-6560f650-2a21-4e2a-a13c-c293ed63244f-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 185 root 37K Jan 28 15:56 /var/data/testing2/_temporary/0/task_202201281556132279227184912186575_0003_m_000002/part-00002-6560f650-2a21-4e2a-a13c-c293ed63244f-c000.snappy.parquet
```

But now if I try loading the data again I get an error:

```
scala> val df3 = spark.read.parquet("/var/data/testing2")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.
```

On the driver pod (which is NOT attached to the shared PV), `/var/data/testing2` is empty which I think is what causes that error.

**My question is**: why does `write.parquet` run on the executors but `read.parquet` apparently runs on the driver?  Won't this be a problem if I have a dataset much larger than the memory available on the driver?

**Solved:** Attaching the PV to the driver pod fixed the issue.  With the PV attached to the driver, the parquet files were written to `/var/data/testing2/` instead of `/var/data/testing2/_temporary...`, and there was a file `_SUCCESS` in `/var/data/testing2`.  So I suspect that even though the parquet files were being generated, the data generation step wasn't actually completing like I thought it was.

Comment: driver builds an execution plan so it needs to know how many partitions/tasks will be required based on the number of files and their sizes. BTW, driver should also commit a  write (move files from `.../_temporary/..` to permanent location), otherwise write job won't succeed either.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue where the driver is running out of memory while reading parquet file partitions. I am also confused why this is happening to the driver.